# Perfect solution for a multiplication game

Tags: game-theory

So I have encountered a question that I am struggling to figure out, what exactly would be considered a perfect way to play a game, especially when this game consists of two players. Its part of Python function that I'm suppose to make.

Question: 
Jacob and Vicky play the fun game of multiplication by multiplying an integer p by one of the numbers 2
to 9. Jacob always starts with p = 1, does his multiplication, then Vicky multiplies the number, then Jacob
and so on. The winner is who first reaches p >= n (when n is a number chosen at the beginning of each
game n>1). Assuming that both of them play perfectly (i.e. Jacob and Vicky play to win, and follow the
perfect strategy to win ). Write a Python function play_fun_game, that consume a positive integer n
and produces True if Vicky wins after playing the game according to the explained rules, otherwise the
function produces False.

These are some of examples for this question.

play_fun_game(17) => True

play_fun_game(35) => False

play_fun_game(190) => True

play_fun_game(771) => False

play_fun_game(20) => False

play_fun_game(3480) => True

play_fun_game(1589) => False

play_fun_game(5768) => True

play_fun_game(36) => False

play_fun_game(2222) => False

play_fun_game(3489) => True

I can understand the smaller numbers like 17 and 20. If Jacob starts at 1 and can only get 2 to 9, then the other player can just get 18 (2 x 9) which is greater than 17. So if the number is 17, Vicky automatically wins, but its a lot harder to find out the winner when the numbers get bigger. I had an idea that each player would multiple by the smallest number (2) until a window of opportunity appears but that doesn't seem right as the tests don't turn out to be the same. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

Jacob wins if $n\leq9,$ Vicky wins if $10\leq n\leq 18,$ Jacob wins if $19\leq n\leq 162,$ Vicky wins if $163\leq n\leq 324,$ Jacob wins if $325\leq n\leq 2916,$ etc.

Comment: The end of Vicky's winning domain is increasing by x 2 from the previous one while the end of Jacob's is increasing by * 9 from the previous one. I am still not sure about the winning strategy, does this mean, that Jacob will always multiple by biggest number in 9 and Vicky will always multiple by the lowest as in 2.  I get the first 2 winning domains, Jacob can obviously win in one step if its between 2 and 9, and if its between 10 and 18 he will obviously lose because regardless what he picks, the opponent will be able to win on the second turn.

Comment: Cont - 18 is because, Jacob knows he cant win and he chooses to go with two so that the biggest number Vicky can achieve is 18 ( 2 x 9). I don't get it at the 19 to 162 part, 162 I would assume is created through (9 x 18) but why exactly is Vicky's winning domain range so small, compared to Jacob, like Vicky's domain end is just 2 x of its beginning.

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen If $19\leq n\leq 81 $ Jacob will choose $\left\lfloor\dfrac {n - 1} {9} \right \rfloor$ first. If $82\leq n\leq 162 $ Jacob will choose $9.$ Whatever number Vicky chooses, Jacob will win.

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen above $162,$ Vicky will choose $\left\lfloor\dfrac {n - 1} {J_1\cdot 9} \right \rfloor$, where $J_1=$ Jason's first choice, etc.

Comment: ok lets say it was 200,  how would I determine J1 since its greater than 162, would it just be 9 as the max?

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen at $n=200$ it doesn't matter what Jason chooses as his first choice, since if Vicky plays optimally, she will win.

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen so if $J_1=2,V_1=\left\lfloor \frac{200-1}{2\cdot 9}\right\rfloor=11,$ if $J_1=3,V_1=\left\lfloor \frac{200-1}{3\cdot 9}\right\rfloor=7,$ etc.

Comment: but Vicky and Jacob both can only choose between 2 and 9. So the 11 case should be invalid but all the higher cases would still work.  Just wondering about Jacob's winning domain of 325 <= n <= 2916 will the formula for choosing number looking something like n - 1 // J1 * V1 * 9?

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen anything over $9$ within that range defaults to $9,$ so yes, that first $V_1$ should read $9.$

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen re your last comment, yes - try and graph the possibilities within each range & you should get a clearer idea of what is going on.

Comment: really appreciate all the help so far but like even knowing the domains doesn't really help me that much when making the function, could you explain to me the strategy for each player given any number (n). not specific decisions in specific domains.

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen do you want to simulate a game up to $n$, or do you want to input a number and return True/False as asked in OP? If latter, you know the sequence already, so you just have to write program that outputs that answer. If former, I suggest you (a) rephrase your question (b) ask as new question with emphasis on strategy / proof rather than solution.

Comment: Im suppose to do the latter which I have accomplished by recursively creating winning domains for True and False and the program works but it doesn't actually simulate the strategy and proof its just if a number is detected in a specific domain it spits out True or  False. I will open a new question about the strategy since I'm interested in it personally.

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen great - I wam interested to see what answer you get :) - Hope hint was (partially) helpful! ;)